# Как использовать std::swap внутри constexpr функции?

Tags: c++

`std::swap` является `constexpr`, начиная с `c++20`.

Поэтому я не могу использовать его в таком случае

```
struct sortable {
    // ...
     
    sortable(int a, int b) : _array({a, b}){
    }         
     
    // Функция является constexpr в c++17.
    template<class T>
    CONSTEXPR_17 void sort(T& first, T& last){
      // ...
      if(*last < *first) {
        std::swap(*first, *last); // Error. Не является constexpr в c++17.
      }
    }

    std::array<int, 2> _array;
};
```

Вместо этого мне нужно писать так:

```
struct sortable {
    template<class T>
    CONSTEXPR_17 void sort(T& first, T& last){
      // ...
      if(*last < *first) {
        // swap
        auto tmp = std::move(*first);
        *first   = std::move(*last);
        *last    = std::move(tmp);
      }
    }
};
```

Есть ли какой-то более элегантный способ?

Comment: Что вы хотите получить и при компиляции в каком компиляторе/стандарте? Непонятна ваша сверхзадача — просто написать какой-то шаблон с использованием `swap`?

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы метод sort был constexpr в c++11-17. Но если я использую std::swap, он не будет constexpr.

Comment: Ну так вы же сами написали — что использовать `swap` в с++17 как constexpr нельзя... Пишете его сами — куда уж элегантнее. Только вот все равно гарантии, что это будет выполняться именно на стадии компиляции, нет — мало ли какие там у вас конструкторы/операторы, `constexpr` или нет...